# Adding Textfield, Button and If-Else Statement Integration to a Website

Tags: php, html

Title might not be clear, let me explain it.

There is a website that I'm making. What I want to do is, there's gonna be textfield and a button. If user enters the correct word (that I set before in codes) clicking the button will forward the user to www.website.com/forward -for example-. It can refresh the page and put the content there too, but I think that requires a lot of work? How can make this happen? What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['code']) && $_POST['code'] == 'YOUR CODE'){
   #your code here
   header("Location: www.website.com/forward");
}
?>
<form method="POST">
     <textarea name="code">Enter Code</textarea><button>Submit</button>
</form>
```